# Can .NET WebApi and Angular >2 share models or view models

Tags: angular, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

Noticed in web api its nice to have a view model layer in between sql models in entity framework and what is presented to front end as endpoints.  But would like to only have to update one set of view models between frontend and middle tier web api services.

Question: Is there a tool or intermediary utility that allows maintaining only one set of models or view models shared between the front end and middle tier between an Angular > 2.0 front end app and a .net WebApi project?

Curently using .net 4.7.2 and Angular 6.

Comment: Yes this is definitely a duplicate question ... appears there are some 3rd  party tools but not apparent if its not built into typescript or .Net WebApi projects or apps by default.

Comment: This is different in one important way... its sharing the view model as opposed to just the class definition file.